# Facebook Following counters Number and Followers Number create On my Site?

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have Created One Site Using html.its Working Well. Now I have To Implement Facebook Following Counters and Followers counter Display On MY site. I don't Know How To create it? i have searched Internet i  a getting answer.

I have Set Follow and Followers  default value Like

```
 36                   2,367
Following             Followers
```

I have set the code for in div tag

```
                           <div class="follow">

                        <div class="col-md-6 two" >

                            <span>36</span>
                            <p>Following</p>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-6 two-left">

                            <span>2,367</span>
                            <p>Followers</p>
                        </div>
```

Please Help Me For this Friends.i want same design Like above code. How to  use   set Following counter and Followers counter in my Site ?   Any Idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Facebook developer page here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments